# Парсер данных с сайта

Tags: php, парсер

Есть задача, перекинуть содержание страниц с одного сайта на другой, конечно, можно сделать это вручную, но было бы интересно, даже для собственного развития попробовать спарсить данные с сайта на свой.
Подскажите как это делается? Много читал, есть встроенные библиотеки на php, и даже есть конкретные примеры, но хотелось бы понять саму суть.

Я правильно понимаю подход? Мы читаем HTML разметку страницы с помощью втроенных библиотек php, потом эти данные передаем в Базу данных нашего сайта и выводим уже на странице? Но как быть если есть и админка у сайта, не будет ли ошибок и противоречий?

Подскажите известные вам ресурсы, книги, примеры, которые я мог бы изучить для ознакомления с данной темой.

Comment: _не будет ли ошибок и противоречий?_ это от вас зависит, как сделаете - так и будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

Если просто надо получить какие-то данные (например ссылки) , то используешь либо какие-то библиотеки, но для обучения curl самое оно. Потом регулярки в помощь. После если останется желание можешь с данными хоть на край земли.
Если по-нормальному надо получить какие-то данные ->ищешь их API и потом нормально работаешь со структурированными данными.
Для  начала почитай https://www.php.net/manual/ru/curl.examples-basic.php